# Ivy Indirect Dependency Listed Twice

Tags: java, scala, ivy

My classpath contains two different versions of an indirect dependency and I do not understand why.

My sub-project ("myJar") depends on a "utils" sub-project that depends on "lib-subprojA". I have the code to all these projects, but they are proprietary, so I cannot post snippets.

```
myProject-myJar -> myProject-utils -> lib-subprojA
```

I made a change in lib-subprojA; the last version before the change was 0.0.100-SNAPSHOT. The version that contains my change is 0.0.101-SNAPSHOT.
When I look at the classpath of "myProject-myJar" I find both "lib-subprojA-0.0.100-SNAPSHOT.jar" (the old version) and "lib-subprojA-0.0.101-SNAPSHOT.jar" (the latest version).
Not sure why both are in classpath, but I cannot get "myProject-myJar" to compile because it uses old version of "lib-subprojA".

This happens in Eclipse (with IvyDE) and sbt (`sbt clean update compile`).
I have no idea why resolving the middle project ("myProject-utils") produces the correct dependency while resolving the leaf project ("myProject-myJar") brings in two versions of the same JAR ("lib-subprojA", versions 0.0.100, 0.0.101).

Is this because intermediate resolution results are cached? If so, how can I delete that cache?

```
lib-subprojA // Made change here. Old version: 0.0.100; new: 0.0.101
lib-subprojB
myProject-utils: dependency ... name="lib-subprojA"    rev="0.0.+" conf="compile->compile(*),master(*);runtime->runtime(*)"
  resolves to: lib-subprojA-0.0.101-SNAPSHOT.jar
myProject-myJar: dependency ... name="myProject-utils" rev="0.0.+" conf="compile->compile(*),master(*);runtime->runtime(*)"
  resolves to: lib-subprojA-0.0.100-SNAPSHOT.jar, lib-subprojA-0.0.101-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

Comment: To clear your cache, you can `rm -rf ~/.ivy2/cache`. There's also a `local` folder in `~/.ivy2` that you can try removing as well (it stores libs that were published using `sbt publishLocal`). There's also a nice tool [here](https://github.com/jrudolph/sbt-dependency-graph) for viewing the dependency graph of your project that may help narrow it down.

Comment: Deleted caches from `~/.ivy2`. Problem remains. I even did numerous builds of `lib-subprojA` (without code changes) hoping version 0.0.100 gets is purged out. I now have dependencies on versions 0.0.100 (old, no good) and 0.0.112 (latest)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that in one of the config files for lib-subprojA we had set `local.ivy.dir` to `${user.home}/ivy2` instead of `${user.home}/.ivy2`. I have spent a few hours tracking a single period character, no bigger than this: `.`

It all works as expected now.